# Django Rest Framework different image size for different account tiers (Basic, Premium)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, membership

There are three bultin account tiers: Basic, Premium and Enterprise:
Users that have "Basic" plan after uploading an image get:

- a link to a thumbnail that's 200px in height
  Users that have "Premium" plan get:
- a link to a thumbnail that's 200px in height
- a link to a thumbnail that's 400px in height
- a link to the originally uploaded image

I have no idea how I can combine the ability to save different resolutions of photos added by the user depending on their membership.
My solution saves one resolution for all users.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image


def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'images/{0}'.format(filename)


class Images(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='author')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 200:
            output_size = (200, 200)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)


class Profile(models.Model):

    MEMBERSHIP = (
        ('BASIC', 'Basic'),
        ('PREMIUM', 'Premium'),
        ('ENTERPRISE', 'Enterprise')
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    membership = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=MEMBERSHIP, default='BASIC')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} {self.membership} Profile'
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from blog.models import Images, Profile



class ImagesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ('author', 'title', 'image')
```

views.py

```
class ImagesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Images.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImagesSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        user = self.request.user
        return Images.objects.filter(author=user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to expand your model and save images in the database in all resolutions:

```
# models.py
class Images(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
    image_200 = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path_200)
    image_400 = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path_200)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img_200 = Image.open(self.image.path)
        img_400 = Image.open(self.image.path)

        output_size_200 = (200, 200)
        output_size_400 = (400, 400)
        img_200.thumbnail(output_size_200)
        img_400.thumbnail(output_size_400)
        img_200.save(self.image_200.path)
        img_400.save(self.image_400.path)
```

Then you need to add serialization depending on user privileges, something like this:

```
# serializers.py
class ImagesBasicUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ('author', 'title', 'image_200')


class ImagesPremiumUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ('author', 'title', 'image_200', 'image_400', 'image')
```

And then serialize the data depending on the user's privileges by overriding the get_serializer_class method in the likeness of this:

```
# views.py
class ImagesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Images.objects.none()
    serializer_class = ImagesBasicUserSerializer
    
    def get_user(self):
        
        user = self.request.user
        return user

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        
        user = self.get_user()
        if user.membership == 'Basic':
            return ImagesBasicUserSerializer
        if user.membership == 'Premium':
            return ImagesPremiumUserSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):

        user = self.get_user()
        return Images.objects.filter(author=user)
```